Error propagation through rotations
Suppose you have a rigid body which goes through a sequence of rotations, each rotation is equal to a rotation matrix multiplied by some small random rotation parametrized by Euler Angles which are gaussian distributed at the origin.
I'm curious as to what the best way to approximate the probability distribution of the final orientation?
One way to do this is parametrize the whole setup with Euler Angles but there are issues with gimbal lock, is there a way to avoid gimbal lock?

Could you use quaternions instead?

Quaternions still suffer from over parametrization, I am not sure how that would be handled.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "over parametrization"; I just figured that by interpreting unit quaternions as living on $S^3$, there might be a more natural distribution to employ there.

By Eulers theorem for $SO(3)$ any rotation can be represented by an arrow  of the undirected eigen-axis  on the northern unit hemisphere and an angle of rotation $\phi \in (-\pi,\pi)$ on the unit circle.
By the law of big numbers for a set of random  walks in a Riemann geometry in independent orthogonal coordinates, the final position from start on the pole with angle 0,   axis and angle are distributed as the solution of the diffusion equation. Its coeffecients come from the metrics, uniform wrt to angle of rotation and spherical on the hemisphere with antipodal points on the equator.
Antipodal points on the equator are identified. In this rotational symmetic case reflecting boundary condition at the equator are justified  because the jump over the equatorial plane $\phi\to \phi \pm \pi$ is without effect on the distribution.
The problem can be simplified using the double cover $SU(2)$ and using a chart with the length of the axis as angle of rotation ranging in $(0,4\pi)$. The center of the sphere of axis arrows at $r=0$ and the boundary sphere at $r=4\pi$ are points and  are identified. The sphere is growing in area in $r\in (0,2\pi)$ and shinks symmetrically for $(r\in (2\pi,4\pi)).$
The positive periodic solution of the diffusion equation on the unit circle symmetric wrt. to $\phi=0 $ is the the Jacobi elliptic theta function $\theta_3(\phi,e^{-t})$.
In Mathematica code
Manipulate[
  Plot[EllipticTheta[3, x/2, E^-\[Tau]], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, ], 
{\[Tau], 0, 7}]


The error plot in x of $\theta_3$ at $t=1$
$$(\partial_t-\partial_x^2)\theta_3(\frac{x}{2},e^{-t})$$ yields

So the parameters are set correctly for the standard diffusion equation on the unit circle with start point 0.
The solution on the hemisphere along a meridian is of course independent of the longitude with start at the pole $\theta=0$.
The distribution along the half meridian $\theta\in  (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ is the fundamental solution of the Legendre equation as series over eigenfunctions of $$-\left((1-z^2) \ J_l'(z) \right)  ' \ = \ l \ (l+1) \ J_l(z) $$
$$\rho(z,t)=\sum_{l=0}^\infty e^{-t\ l \ (l+1)} \ J_l(z)$$
